# How to override default behaviour when select a date using jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What I want to do is to add a class on the `<td>` of the date selected.

I thought I could use `onSelect`, but it only gives me the date string or the current datepicker instance which is the entire calendar.

I then tried to add a event to the `<td>` element, so when I click on the date, I could get the element and add a class to it. In my event the element's class got changed ok, but once it finishes, the class got changed back to the jQuery ui class. So I think my event actually got trigged before jQuery-ui datepicker click event, so it overwrites my class. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

When `td` is clicked you can try to `setTimeout`  and after a while set the css class.

Comment: I can do that, but it will be unpredictable, how long should I set the time out? It depends on user's machine, some machine might be faster or slower. So I don't think it's a good idea. But thanks for the suggestion.